# JSON/jQuery Syntax issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to read a list of images from a folder to create DIVs with image backgrounds (for use as an image slider). The jQuery I've written is as follows:

```
$.getJSON('../functions.php', function(images) {
  images.each( function() {
    $('#main').prepend('<div class="slider" style="background-image:url(' + ' (this) + ');"></div>');
  });
});
```

This isn't working, unfortunately... The error message I get in console is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax highlighting in SO gave me the clue that you need to change it to this:

```
$('#main').prepend('<div class="slider" style="background-image:url(' + this + ');"></div>');
```

You had an extra quote in there (and don't need the `()` around `this`...although it wouldn't hurt.

**UPDATE**:

After the quoting issue was taken care of and you received the other ERROR, the problem seemed to be that your `images` JSON was trying to be iterated over with `.each`, which cannot be used on an object literal. `.each` is used either on a jQuery object (so wrap `images` with `$()`) or with the call to iterate over objects/arrays (`$.each()`). You need to use something like:

```
$.each(images, function () {    // <---- I prefer
// or
$(images).each(function () {
```

Comment: Yes, sort of... Error message I'm getting now is: Uncaught TypeError: Object gallery/01_New/Steam.jpg,gallery/01_New/3059.jpg,gallery/01_New/Billow.jpg has no method 'each'

Comment: You need to wrap it, `$(images).each()` or `$.each(images, function...`

Comment: @adeneo Although not technically different, I would use `$.each(images)`

Comment: @Ian, what's the difference between the two options?  Why do you prefer the former?

Comment: `$.each` Is supposedly a general iterating function that takes pretty much anything, while `$(element).each()` only iterates jQuery objects, but then again almost anything wrapped in `$()` is a valid jQuery object.

Comment: @Ian Reason for down-vote?  You had 4719 and now you have 4728.

Comment: @NaOH So, the `$.each` method is meant for arrays/objects - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ ...while the `$(selector).each` is meant to iterate over the matched DOM elements. In your case, if you used `$(images)`, you're wrapping the array in a jQuery object (which I'm not entirely sure what actually happens with that situation, other than the fact that it still works). So it will still iterate through the items, but it's not the "best"...I'm not sure what word to use.

Comment: Oh jeez, no fighting!  Thanks for your help, everyone!

Comment: @Daedalus Haha I don't care about the points. You originally had the right answer. But the second error came up and I saw you edit and use the solution by adeneo (whether you thought of it on your own or not)...and you didn't bother explaining it. It was like your own way of saying "I knew that should've been done that way" without any tracking, because it hadn't been 5 minutes and your edit wasn't recorded. If you explain why they should wrap `images` in `$()` then I'll be happy to vote up because it's a just-as-valid answer.

Comment: @Daedalus - who knows why people downvote, I've "stolen" answers that have hundreds of upvotes and are generally considered "the" way of doing it, and recieved plenty of downvotes on almost the exact same answer. The problem sometimes is that a lot of voters don't understand the answers, and just upvotes and downvotes what everyone else does, and some people just downvote for fun. Get over it!

Comment: @Ian Thank you for finally explaining.  I will edit the answer and explain why images should be wrapped, though as you already stated, it goes to preference between that and `$.each()`.  I did see adeneo's comment, and I realized my own error, so I tried to rectify it, but I failed to explain it, which is a fine reason for a down vote.. not to say that it isn't, I mean.  As to you adeneo, I guess I kind of have a slight ocd about even numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You don't close your quote properly.  Aside from that, assuming that `images` is an array, you need to wrap it in the jQuery object in order to get access to the object's methods, `$.each()` being one of them.  Otherwise, as @Ian has already stated, you could use `$.each(array, function() { //do stuff });` in a different light, and simply pass the array as the first variable, with whatever you do with it with an anonymous function.

As you said previously you were color-blind, as syntax-highlighting is then useless to you, I would recommend you at least count your quote pairs.  On heavily verbose code.. this would become difficult.. so the only other thing I can suggest is an IDE(integrated development environment), such as NetBeans(what I personally use).

```
$.getJSON('../functions.php', function(images) {
    $(images).each( function() {
        $('#main').prepend('<div class="slider" style="background-image:url(' + this + ');"></div>');
    });
});
```